# Since I upgrade flutter to 2.5 latest version ,the command "Downloading iOS tools"keep running for very long Time, note Internet connection is so good

Tags: flutter, dart

here .......
[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7Q2Q.png)

the app didn't work even from terminal, and the compiler couldn't download aircrafts folder .. gives me this error message in offline running or mode:

Failed to download https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/flutter/f0826da7ef2d301eb8f4ead91aaf026aa2b52881/ios/artifacts.zip. Ensure you have network connectivity and then try again.
SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'storage.googleapis.com' (OS Error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known, errno = 8

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

use VPN with good internet to download it.